# Вызов exe файла через bat файл

Tags: c#, bat

Есть файл exe(консольное приложение)  и bat файл. Как сделать вызов exe файла через bat с передачей в параметр IP адреса, который хранится в файле со списком ip адресов?
Никогда не писал bat файлы, хотелось бы увидеть маленький пример, или ссылку на статью.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. В чем именно сложность: запуск exe, передача параметра, обработка списка и т.д.?

Comment: Сложность в передаче параметра, который хранится в отельном файле

Comment: `set /p ip=<file.txt` - читаем из файла в переменную. `program.exe %ip%` - запускаем программу с параметром

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо) Есть еще такой вопрос, как на c# принять переданный параметр из bat, например записать в переменную, или как это правильно делается.

Comment: `Main(string[] args)` - вот параметры командной строки. / Только что забанили одного участника сайта за крепкие выражения. Я сейчас тоже не сдержусь... Задрали такие вопросы: "Есть файл exe", а далее оказывается, что ничего на самом деле нет, способ передачи данных не определён и ... ладно, сдержусь.

Comment: Если вы только пишете программу на C#, то почему бы прямо в ней не читать тот файл? Зачем промежуточный bat-файл?

Comment: Документация: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-5.0), [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/how-to-display-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Если в файле не одно значение, а список, то читать их нужно в цикле. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069068/5045688

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Такие условия тестового задания, не я придумываю

Comment: Отпишитесь потом о результате: получилось ли сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, благодаря ссылкам выше, все удалось) Сейчас последнюю задачу решаю на c#, звучит так: "фильтр должен подхватывать обновления в файле с информацией по IP без
перезагрузки приложения". Типо мы в файл добавляем строку и она должна без перезагрузки появится в консоле. Я правильно понимаю, это делается через многопоточность?

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov большое спасибо!)